# Display material-ui cards one next each other

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I was trying to display cards inside a mapping loop using also the Grid like that.

```
 <div className={classes.root}>
              {data.tableData.childRows.map((el: any, idx: number) => {
                return (
                  <Grid
                    container
                    spacing={2}
                    direction="row"
                    justify="flex-start"
                    alignItems="flex-start"
                  >
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                      <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
                        <CardContent>
                          <Typography color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
                            Name: {data.name}
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography color="textPrimary">
                            Email: {data.email}
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography color="textPrimary">
                            Gateway: {el.gateway}
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography color="textPrimary">
                            ID: {el.id}
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography color="textPrimary">
                            Created: {el.creationDate}
                          </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                          <Button
                            size="small"
                            onClick={() => {
                              alert("button clicked" + data.email);
                            }}
                          >
                            Action
                          </Button>
                        </CardActions>
                      </Card>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                );
              })}
            </div>
```

My makeStyle is that

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
```

but the cards are visualized one on top of the other aligned to the left.
How can I display in a row the cards equally spaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent `div` element needs to have `display: flex` to visualize them inline. Try code from below

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      display: 'flex'
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
```

In case you want to learn more about flexbox, checkout nice guideline on the link below.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @javaFE if you found this answer useful which it looks like you did because is marked as answer, can you upvote it as well please ? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<Grid
        container
        spacing={2}
        direction="row"
        justify="space-between"
        alignItems="center"
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

Use xs and xl for respective small or large screens to render card next to other in Grid.

Example

```
<Grid xs={4}>    
</Grid>
```